# How to describe a person who always prefers things from other countries but not from their home countries?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example: this person thinks that the goods from other countries is always better than his/her own country's.

Comment: There are specific terms for particular home/foreign country pairs, but they aren't usually restricted to just products from the foreign country, nor that all domestic products are inferior to the products of that foreign country. Rather, they typically indicate a fascination for a native of one culture with the cultural products of another. For example, *weeaboo* for a Westener fascinated with Japan.

Comment: "The idiot who praises, with enthusiastic tone, / All centuries but this and every country but his own" is an item on Ko-Ko's "itltle list of society offenders who . . . never would be missed" in Gilbert & Sullivan's *The Mikado.*

Comment: "Aaaaaand they'll none of them be missed!  They'll none ... of ... them .. be ... missed!"

Comment: How about a snob?

Answer (score 32):

**Xenophilia**

> Xenophily or xenophilia means an affection for unknown/foreign objects or people. It is the opposite of xenophobia or xenophoby. The word is a modern coinage from the Greek "xenos" (ξένος) (stranger, unknown, foreign) and "philia" (φιλία) (love, attraction), though the word itself is not found in classical Greek.
>
> <sub>[*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenophilia)</sub>

As suggested by @Monsoor, I should add the term for a *person* who loves foreign cultures, manners, and people is a **xenophile**.

Comment: On the nose! And so quick! Faster than I wrote my shorter, wringer comment. Well done.

Comment: Although it is a minor observation, to be technically correct, should the specific answer to this question be "Xenophile" and not "Xenophilia". This is because, we are describing the person and not the "verb" form of the same.

Comment: *Ding ding!* "Xenophilia" is the first word that came to mind, dangit.

Comment: Then I guess I'm xenophile :-)

Comment: I can't say for English, but in Russian, "xenophob" is a politically correct synonym for nationalist. the word "xenophile" doesn't remind me of goods, but merely has to do with social way or sympathy to foreign culture or people, things. (at least in Russian language)